# change tuple in list output python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I got a dictionary like below:

```
a = [('Ma', [128.35226732698018]), ('Ta', [56.42857142857143]), ('Eg', [46.35428571428572]), ('Ky', [41.6177429876057])]
```

the thing I'd like to output is like that:

```
Ma (128.35)
Ta (56.43)
Eg (46.35)
Ky (41.62)
```

How could I get rid of both list and tuple and change the number into `float:2f`?

Comment: the thing I'd like to output is like that:

Ma (128.35) \nTa (56.43)\n Eg (46.35)\n Ky (41.62)

Comment: show what you have tried??

Comment: there are no `dictionaries` in your example.

Comment: _"I got a dictionary like below:"_  -That's not a dictionary, it's a _**list of tuples**_.

Comment: just `loop` through it and in every iteration `print` using the curly bracers notation. e.g., `'{:.2f}'.format(2.311541651)`. You can do this yourself easily.

Comment: Iterate through the list using string formatting (e.g. `str.format()`) to print it how you want. What are you getting stuck on?

Comment: I am not sure,it's do looks like tuple in list,but I use a = defaultdict(list) before

Comment: You have obviously reassigned `a` to this list of tuples, it doesn't matter what you assigned it to before.

Comment: thanks guys,I have got it:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = [('Ma', [128.35226732698018]), ('Ta', [56.42857142857143]), ('Eg', [46.35428571428572]), ('Ky', [41.6177429876057])]

for k in a:

    print(k[0], '{:.2f}'.format(k[1][0]))
```

Answer (score 3):

The following uses **value unpacking** and **string formating**, both very important to learn about:

```
a = [('Ma', [128.35226732698018]), ('Ta', [56.42857142857143]), ('Eg', [46.35428571428572]), ('Ky', [41.6177429876057])]

for k, v in a:
    print('{} ({:.2f})'.format(k, *v))
```

Outputs:

```
Ma (128.35)
Ta (56.43)
Eg (46.35)
Ky (41.62)
```

---

As @Ajax1234 states, the *unpacking* performed by the `*` operator only workds with Python 3. If you are using Python 2 you can replace `*v` with `v[0]`. Note that the latter works with both.

Comment: Nice solution! However, you may want to add the `*v` is only supported in Python3, so if the OP is using Python2, a `SyntaxError` will occur.

Comment: @Ajax1234 Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack the values and round:

```
a = [('Ma', [128.35226732698018]), ('Ta', [56.42857142857143]), ('Eg', [46.35428571428572]), ('Ky', [41.6177429876057])]

for name, [value] in a:
    print(name, "({})".format(round(value, 2)))
```

Final Output:

```
Ma (128.35)
Ta (56.43)
Eg (46.35)
Ky (41.62)
```

Comment: thanks!it worked,I leart that [value] could be an element,but I do need a (128.35)

Comment: @Ajax1234 i did not dv. Yeah, its fixed now. I like the `[value]` trick

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [('Ma', [128.35226732698018]), ('Ta', [56.42857142857143]), ('Eg', [46.35428571428572]), ('Ky', [41.6177429876057])]
[print(elem[0],'('+str(round(elem[1][0],2))+')') for elem in a]
```

How about a list comprehension.